# Tkinter の tree.view でフォーカスを複数行に対して行いたい

Tags: python, tkinter, tk

Tkinter の `tree.view` でフォーカスを複数行に対して行いたい。

例えばサンプルコードのように10行の `tree.view` リストから "3"、"4" だけフォーカスしたいがなぜか "4" だけしかフォーカスされません。

複数行選択状態にする方法をご存知の方いらっしゃったら、ご教示いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 実行画面]

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

num_frame = tk.Tk() # ルートフレーム作成
num_frame.title("") # タイトル設定
num_frame.geometry("180x306") # 画面サイズ設定
num_frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(num_frame,font=("",12),bd=2,padx=5,pady=5,relief="ridge",labelanchor='nw',text="",width=150,height=240,bg="#00599D")
num_frame1.pack(fill="both")
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview",font=("",12)) # TreeViewのフォントサイズの変更
style.configure("Treeview.Heading",font=("",14,"bold")) # ヘッダのフォントサイズの変更と太字の設定
tree = ttk.Treeview(num_frame1,height=100)
tree["columns"] = (1)
tree["show"] = "headings" # 表スタイルの設定
tree.column(1,width=100)
tree.pack()
num_lst = ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
i = 0 # 初期化
for line in num_lst:
    iid = tree.insert("","end",tags=i,values=(line))
    # tagが奇数か偶数か判定して背景色を変える
    if line == "3" or line == "4" :
        tree.focus(iid) # データのフォーカス(プログラム上で内部的に選択した状態)
        tree.selection_set(iid) # データの選択(見た目上で選択された状態)
```

Answer (score 1):

こちらの記事を参考に、複数選択する場合は`selection_set()`ではなく`selection_add()`か`selection_toggle()`にすれば良いでしょう。

[Tk Treeview Focus(). How do I Get Multiple Selected Lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48867800/9014308)

> Use ttk.treeview.selection().
> It gives the selected items. See also other Treeview methods with selection prefix such as,
> 選択したアイテムが表示されます。 以下のような選択接頭辞を持つ他のTreeviewメソッドも参照してください。
>
> ```
> selection_add
> selection_remove
> selection_toggle
> ```

Comment: selection_addでうまくいきました。
あとtree.focus(iid)は無くても内部的選択状態になっているようです。
ありがとうございました。